# How to create an event in wxWidgets when cursor comes to wxTextCtrl

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I am creating `wxTextCtrl` for `username` and `password`. I want this functionality: 1) when user enters username and goes to password textbox, I am using `wxSET_EVT_FOCUS` on `password` and checking if given username is in our DB, if it is present in our DB I have to open a new frame with `wxWebView`. User needs to enter password in new window and click OK then this new frame will automatically close. When this new frame opens I am disabling username and password textboxes in old window. 2) If user manually closes this new window then I am enabling username and password textboxes again.

In second case I am facing problem, that wxEVT_SET_FOCUS keeps on executing, is there any way to remove focus from wxTextCtrl?

Comment: wxEVT_SETYFOCUS?

Answer (score 1):

`wxFocusEvent`, and you can search the samples in case you don't know how to handle it.

Comment: To be even more precise, the OP needs to handle `wxEVT_SET_FOCUS`.

Comment: Thank you. I used `wxEVT_SET_FOCUS`, but now I am facing one more problem, when `wxEVT_SET_FOCUS` handler function finishes, and if I click again on password textbox, cursor does not come in the password textbox. Updated the question. Can you please help ? @VZ.

Comment: Did you try Skip()-ing the event?

Comment: @aromahola This is not an appropriate use of comments.

Comment: @aromahola Please stop with these comments.